# How to block/lock a textbox?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using visual studio 2013. The text in textbox3 of my program can be edited by the user. I want to fix text in it.To do that user must be unable to edit the text in that textbox. How to do that.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you have currently?

Comment: As @Alok mentioned above please post some information about your programming language and some code you tried. So, it's easier to help and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code and you'll get a window with TextBox1 disabled and TextBox2 enabled.

```
TextBox1.Text = "ContentOfTextBox1" 'fill text box
TextBox1.Enabled = False            'disable text box
```

or

```
TextBox1.Text = "ContentOfTextBox1";
TextBox1.Enabled = false;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set .ReadOnly property to True.As an example,

```
TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
```

Here the user can't edit textbox1.